# What's wrong with this htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a dynamic page that get the "p" parameter to show contents:

```
m.mydomain.com/index.php?p=key
```

I would like some sort of clean url.

This is my actual htaccess:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

so:

```
m.mydomain.com/key -> doesn't work (404 page)
m.mydomain.com/index/key -> blank page
```

how to get a m.mydomain.com/key ?

Please help me, I'm going crazy!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have tested and working

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that your RewriteRule will catch direct calls to index.php, and attempt to redirect

```
m.mydomain.com/index.php
```

to

```
m.mydomain.com/index.php?p=index.php
```

You can prevent that by first catching the "index.php" path with a separate rewrite rule that looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(index.php) - [L]
```

But I don't think the lack of that should be causing your problem.  Maybe there's another rule in a different .htaccess or web server config file that's interfering?  I ask that because I had no problems with the following:

```
# .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(index.php) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note: I took out the **AddType x-mapp-php5 .php** because that wasn't working on my setup. I don't know if that's related to your problem or not, but you might want to wrap that in an **<IfModule>** to be safe, as suggested at [How to support "AddType x-mapp-php5 .php" on my development machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094310/how-to-support-addtype-x-mapp-php5-php-on-my-development-machine)

Combining it all together, this (also) worked for me:

```
# .htaccess
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(index.php) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```